# Declaring abstract the method implemented from an interface

Tags: php

I wonder if it is possible to not implement a method coming from an interface and let child class do it. 
For example :

```
abstract class Foo implements Bar
{
    public abstract methodFromBar();
}
```

And then :

```
class SubFoo extends Foo
{
    public methodFromBar()
    {
        // Implementation...
    }
}
```

The idea behind this is to simplify development and just specifying that the subclass extends from the main class instead of writing again that the subclass implements the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to mention the interface method in the parent class at all. If it doesn't implement the interfaces listed, then PHP will require that the subclass fulfills the contract instead. This will work fine:

```
interface Bar
{
    public function methodFromBar();
}

abstract class Foo implements Bar
{
}

class SubFoo extends Foo
{
    public function methodFromBar()
    {
        echo 'Hello world';
    }
}

$subFoo = (new SubFoo)->methodFromBar();
// Hello world
```

See https://eval.in/1016337

If the subclass does not implement the method, you'll receive a message along the lines of

> Fatal error: Class SubFoo contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Bar::methodFromBar)

Whether or not you think it's *a good idea* for an abstract class to implement an interface is [probably a discussion for another site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163641/interfaces-on-an-abstract-class).